# Absolute and Conditional Convergence in Spivak

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

This is question 5 Chapter 23 from Spivak:

I have already proved a) which said

Prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then so does $\sum (a_n)^3$

and part b said show that this is not true for conditional convergence.

Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the series
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} -\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}} -\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{3}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}} -\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{4}}+  \dots.$$
The series converges to $0$. The sum of the cubes does not converge. The partial sums wiggle a little around $-6$ times the harmonic series.

Comment: Is there no danger of doing something like $\sum \limits_{n\in \Bbb N}(-1)^n=0$?

Comment: Not here! The terms have limit $0$.